# jars to connect Spark 2 with HBase integration using python

Tags: python, pyspark, hbase, apache-spark-2.0

I am using `pyspark` in Spark 2, Is there any jars to connect `HBase` with `pyspark` available.

please help me with the sample code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative to the answer before:

I am using the hortonworks spark hbase connector. You can find it on [github](https://github.com/hortonworks-spark/shc). They introduced the connector on a [spark summit](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kU45zMl7TqA). At the end of the talk there is also a live demo with some example code. Hope, it helps.

**--- EDIT ---**

The code in the example is written in scala, but the connector also works with pyspark. Here a write/read example:

Start the PySpark-Shell with the connector (Maybe you have to use another version of the package for your setup - check out the introductions and conversations on github).

```
pyspark --master yarn --packages com.hortonworks.shc:shc-core:1.1.0.2.6.5.2-8 --repositories http://nexus-private.hortonworks.com/nexus/content/groups/public/
```

Create a sql-context and define the datasouce

```
sqlc = SQLContext(sc)
data_source_format = 'org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.hbase'
```

Next we have to define a catalog, which is the connector readable table structure. When you have access to the default namespace of hbase, replace YourNameSpace with default. When not, insert your accessible namespace.

```
catalog = ''.join("""{
    "table":{"namespace":"YourNameSpace", "name":"TestTable", "tableCoder":"PrimitiveType"},
    "rowkey":"key",
    "columns":{
        "ID":{"cf":"rowkey", "col":"key", "type":"string"},
        "DATA":{"cf":"data", "col":"", "type":"string"}
        }
    }""".split())
```

To create a hbase table and write something in it we create a suitable dataframe with some data ...

```
df = sc.parallelize([('1', 'Moin'), ('2', 'Hello'), ('3', 'Hallo')]).toDF(schema=['ID', 'DATA'])
```

... and save it to hbase.

```
df.write.options(catalog=catalog, newtable = 5).format(data_source_format).save()
```

Now we can read the content out of our hbase table and save it to a variable:

```
df_read = sqlc.read.options(catalog=catalog).format(data_source_format).load()
```

Check:

```
>>> df_read.show()
+---+-----+                                                                     
| ID| DATA|
+---+-----+
|  1| Moin|
|  2|Hello|
|  3|Hallo|
+---+-----+
```

*- Tested with PySpark 2 on HDP 2.5*

Answer (score 1):

You can visit this [link](https://spark-packages.org/package/nerdammer/spark-hbase-connector) to see the connectors available in Spark.

More information available on this [link](https://github.com/nerdammer/spark-hbase-connector). Read the Readme.md for details.

Here is the dependencies you have to add.

You can just add the following dependency in sbt:

```
libraryDependencies += "it.nerdammer.bigdata" % "spark-hbase-connector_2.10" % "1.0.3"
```

The Maven style version of the dependency is:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>it.nerdammer.bigdata</groupId>
  <artifactId>spark-hbase-connector_2.10</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Sample Code:

```
val sparkConf = new SparkConf()
...
sparkConf.set("spark.hbase.host", "thehost")
...
val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)
```

**Writing to HBase (Basic)**

Writing to HBase is very easy. Remember to import the implicit conversions:

```
import it.nerdammer.spark.hbase._
```

You have just to create a sample RDD, as the following one:

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(1 to 100)
            .map(i => (i.toString, i+1, "Hello"))
```

This rdd is made of tuples like ("1", 2, "Hello") or ("27", 28, "Hello"). The first element of each tuple is considered the row id, the others will be assigned to columns.

```
rdd.toHBaseTable("mytable")
    .toColumns("column1", "column2")
    .inColumnFamily("mycf")
    .save()
```

You are done. HBase now contains 100 rows in table mytable, each row containing two values for columns mycf:column1 and mycf:column2.

**Reading from HBase (Basic)**

Reading from HBase is easier. Remember to import the implicit conversions:

```
import it.nerdammer.spark.hbase._
```

If you want to read the data written in the previous example, you just need to write:

```
val hBaseRDD = sc.hbaseTable[(String, Int, String)]("mytable")
    .select("column1", "column2")
    .inColumnFamily("mycf")
```

Hope, this helps.